# Using Poincaré-Bendixson to prove that $z^{\prime\prime}+(z^2+{z^{\prime}}^4-2)z=0$ has a periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show the existence of a nontrivial
periodic solution of the differential equation
$$
z^{\prime\prime}+(z^2+{z^{\prime}}^4-2)z=0.
$$
Start with usual substitution $x=z,\,y=dx/dt$, thus
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)=2xy(3-x^2-y^4).
$$
But I do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: It is a problem from Section 4.8 in _Differential Equations and Their Applications_.